# Receiving share intent in Flutter (Receiving URL)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, share-intent

I am trying to make a Flutter app that will receive share intent from the browser.
I was able to find a package that lets me receive intents like text, image, video and links but what I need is the URL of the content's origin.
For example if I share a image from a website [www.website.com/products?id=123](http://www.website.com/products?id=123), my app needs to receive [www.website.com/products?id=123](http://www.website.com/products?id=123).

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Dynamic links